# Alfresco :process.bpmn20.xml file how can i get variable from java delegate code

Tags: java, alfresco

Alfresco process.bpmn20.xml file how can i access java delegate variable is possible please help me out

Here

```
     var procInstVariable = execution.getVariable('trainername') //java delegate variable
```

java delegte code variable but i am getting error

Error:

> Not defind node

Example code:

```
<serviceTask id="serviceTask3" name="Attach Training Curriculum Template Document" activiti:class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.script.AlfrescoScriptDelegate">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:field name="script">
          <activiti:expression><![CDATA[
         var procInstVariable = execution.getVariable('trainername') //java delegate variable 
var dest= companyhome.childByNamePath("Sites/test/documentLibrary/"+procInstVariable);
     bpm_package.addNode(dest);
]]></activiti:expression>
        </activiti:field>
      </extensionElements>
    </serviceTask>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating variable in BPMN file and accessing them into Java Delegate**

For ex in bpmn file,

```
execution.setVariable('trainername','SOME_TRAINER');
```

Now you can access the trainername in the java delegate otherwise, you may get NPE.

In Java code

```
var procInstVariable = execution.getVariable('trainername')
```

or

```
String procInstVariable =(String) execution.getVariable('trainername')
```

**Creating workflow variable in Java delegate and accessing them into workflow**

In your java delegate code,

```
execution.setVariable('trainername','SOME_TRAINER');
```

You can access in BPMN file like,

```
var procInstVariable = execution.getVariable('trainername')
```

Please let me know, if I understood wrongly or any help on this.